# TimerTask() still runs in background, even when the app in exited android

Tags: android, timertask

I am developing an app that shows AddScreen every 1 minutes , usin TimerTask() concept,

The problem is the AddScreen is shown every 1 minutes ,even when the app is not currently open that is exited

AdSplashScheduleTime.java

```
public class AdSplashScheduleTime{

    Activity activity;

    public AdSplashScheduleTime(Activity a){
        this.activity=a;

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {      

            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent viewTargetActivity = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), AdSplashCopy.class);
                        activity.startActivity(viewTargetActivity);
                    }
                });
            }
        },60000, 60000);// 5 minutes        

    }


}
```

DiamondWorldMenus.java // Home screen

```
public class DiamondWorldMenus extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {

AdSplashScheduleTime scheduleTime;

onCreate(......){

scheduleTime=new AdSplashScheduleTime(this);

}

}
```

Comment: cancel the timer in `onPause()` of the activity

Comment: You mean in DiamondWorldMenus.java ??

Comment: yes you can cancel the timer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancel your timertask when you switch from one activity to another like this

```
if(myTimer != null) {
  myTimer.cancel();
  myTimer.purge()
  myTimer = null;
}
```

Comment: @karthik you don't have a myTimer defined in activity class. Have a method in `AdSplashScheduleTime` like cancelTimer and cancel the timer there. Call that method in your activity class when you need to cancel the timer.